# Buying domain, parking and google search position

Tags: google, google-analytics, domains, google-search, sem

I am buying domain that is well positioned in google search. I will be moving it to new host to park it there. The new domain will be pointing to my existing website.

What will be the effect on positioning in google? Do I assume correctly it will lose it current rank?

Comment: To add to the canonical question, if you don't do a redirect you will have duplicate content which will also be bad for your SEO efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just buying a domain and you're putting new website on that domain then yes, it will lose its current rank because it's all new on the page, and you'll need to do a proper links, and seo to get it back.

Just put your logic up, I'll give you an example to think about:

If you have `www.domain.com/shop/example` on old page, and on new page it's not there, then what do you think it's going to happen?

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. Seems logic, but always good to have confirmation. Cheers ! :)